# Header location works inconsistently on chrome?

Tags: php, html, header, location

So i have this webshop running on a server, it's working fine on every pc i have been able to get my hands on. but for some reason quite often customers still have problems with one header(location ) to a payment site. I checked everything codewise and tried a hundred different ways of breaking the payment link but haven't found one.

I'm assuming it's the header(location: ...) or the fact that it's three in a row (some php only verification pages inbetween) which might give some version trouble but i'm only guessing.

snip out of the index.php

```
ob_start();
require_once($Content_Path);
$zpfw_page_output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();


//************************************************
// Include the requested header / footer / etc..
//************************************************

//Here we include the HEADER HTML.
require_once($Config['AbsolutePath'] . '_headers/' .        $Config['HeaderFilename']);


//Here we include the PHP PAGE.
echo $zpfw_page_output;


//Here we include the FOOTER HTML.
require_once($Config['AbsolutePath'] . '_footers/' . $Config['FooterFilename']);
```

The Content page is the only thing that changes ($Content_Path) So the customers puts hit products that he wants to buy in his basket and goes towards checkout, now every post done on our pages go to a posttogethandler to make it seo friendly (the indexpages uses the first 2 parameters (www.google.nl/module/page/test)
to change the content path everything behind that are used as parameters $_Get[Param1] = 'test'

posttogethandler.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST))
{
    include '../../../_bootstrap.php';
    if(!empty($_POST['m']) && !empty($_POST['c']))
    {
        $post_string = '';
        foreach($_POST as $key => $postitem)
        {
            if($key == 'm')
            {

            }
            elseif($key== 'c')
            {

            }
            else
            {
                $post_string = $post_string.$postitem.'/';
            }
        }
    header('location:'.$Config['AbsoluteURL'].$_POST['m'].'/'.$_POST['c'].'/'.$post_string);
    }
}
```

and for the actual check which creates a mollie payment and sends to person to the payment (again i will shorten it a bit to only containt the code it passes through if nothing is wrong) (No echo commands exist in this file)

```
<?php
$mollie = new Mollie_API_Client();
$mollie->setApiKey($Config['Mollie']['Api_Key']);

if(!empty($_GET['param1']) && $_GET['param1'] == 'checkout' && !empty($_SESSION['Customer_ID']))
{

/* alot of checks and inserts into mysql database to keep track */


if(!empty($_GET['param3']) && $_GET['param3'] == 'secretcode')
{
    //for skipping payment
    header('Location: ' . $Config['AbsoluteURL'] . 'account/order/' . $uniqueID);
    exit;
}
else
{
    $payment = $mollie->payments->create(array(
        "amount"      => mollieCartPriceIncTaxes($_SESSION['cart'],$_SESSION['Customer_ID'])[0],
        "description" => "Payment for ...",
        "redirectUrl" => $Config['AbsoluteURL']."account/order/payment/".$uniqueID."",
        "webhookUrl" => $Config['AbsoluteURL']."cart/checkout/webhook"
    ));
    $payment = $mollie->payments->get($payment->id);

    zp_mysqli_query("Update orders set Order_MollieID = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($payment->id)."' where Order_ID = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($uniqueID)."'");

    if(!empty($_SESSION['pick_up']))
    {
        unset($_SESSION['pick_up']);
    }

    header("Location: " . $payment->getPaymentUrl()."/#");
    exit;
}
}
```

I'll edit it some more in a few hours, need to go now. this is hosted on a server so i've checked for html code being send first but can't find any nor experience any problems with it on any pc i've tried to open the website with.

any pointers would be much appreciated!

EDIT:

It seems to be a problem with redirecting to a page outside of the domain. I'm remaking the page so the button is a direct link to the payment page. This seems to work.